# Избежать добавления надписи к каждой записи

Tags: javascript

в таблицу истории добавляет к каждой записи надпись *SteamID*, как этого избежать?

```
$('#historys').append(`
    <h3>История</h3>
    <table id="historys">
        <thead>
            <tr class="row">
                <th class="nyr">SteamID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cell">${UserId}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    `);
```

Comment: А что вы именно хотите вместо __SteamID__?

Comment: Хочу что было название колонки и под ними все ид, а сейчас он выводит название колонки под ним ид, затем опять название колонци и под ним ид и тд

Comment: @MegaRoks так уберите эту строку из цикла. Выведите ее один раз перед циклом (шапку), а ID выводите в цикле.

Comment: Это я понимаю, но как сделать что бы появилась  название колонки и под ним ид, оставить в цикле только <td class="cell">${UserId}</td> а остальное куда?

Comment: А остальное - то есть шапку - вынести отдельным append'ом перед циклом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
userIds.forEach(function(userId) {
  $('#historys').append(`
      <tr class="row">
           <td class="cell">${UserId}</td>
       </tr>
  `);
});
```

```html
<h3>История</h3>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="row">
      <th class="nyr">SteamID</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="historys">
      
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**userIds** это массив всех id